# How to set background color of td in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am coding css for tabs which there are two rows (there are many tabs) in table. I want to set background color to them,

This is HTML:

```
<table>

    <!--profile-->
    <tr><td colspan="3">profile</td></tr>

    <!--tabs 2 rows-->
    <div class="tab_links">
    <!--row 1-->
    <tr>
        <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--row 2-->
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a></td>
    </tr>
    </div>

    <!--detail of tab-->
    <tr><td colspan="3">detail of tab</td></tr>

</table>
```

I try to code CSS, but it isn't work.

This is CSS:

```
.tab_links td {
    background:#7fb5da;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: that's not valid HTML - you cannot have a `<div>` as the child of a `<table>`.

Comment: HI, Why are you adding div without wrapping it in tr td , its purely bad structure

Comment: If you use valid HTML, and don't try to nest `<div>` elements improperly, your CSS would work. Add the relevant class-name to a `<tr>` element, or a `<tbody>`. If you right click that `<table>` element, and 'inspect element,' you'll see the DOM doesn't match the CSS selector (the `<div>` will likely follow the `<table>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one reason that your styling isn't applied, that's because the selector you supply `.tab_links td` is never matched by the document. This is because, when constructing the DOM (the Document Object Model) the browser does not maintain invalid HTML, it tries to 'rescue' it. This is a feature, and not a bug. For example, the following (abbreviated and *invalid*) HTML:

```
<table>
    <div class="tab_links">
    <!--row 1-->
    <tr>
        <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--row 2-->
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

Is, when constructing the DOM, converted (tested in Chrome 40.x/Windows 8.1) to:

```
<div class="tab_links">
    <!--row 1-->
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--row 2-->
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a>    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the `<div>` element now precedes the `<table>`? Also, the browser adds a (technically) optional `<tbody>` element to wrap the `<tr>` elements; but that's not terribly relevant.

So: the problem becomes the `<div>` being in the wrong place; the *only* valid elements to be nested directly within a `<table>` element are: `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tr>`<sup>1</sup>.

The solution I'd suggest, since you seem to want to group a number of `<tr>` elements together, is to wrap those elements with a `<tbody>`, and assign the relevant class-name to *that* element, which similarly, but more semantically, groups them together:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="tab_links">
        <tr>
            <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a>    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--row 2-->
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a>    
            </td>
            <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.tab_links td {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #66f;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="tab_links">
    <tr>
      <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a> 
      </td>
      <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a> 
      </td>
      <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--row 2-->
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a> 
      </td>
      <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a> 
      </td>
      <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
- [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).
- [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).
- [`<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot).
- [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).
- [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

---

1. The browser will, as demonstrated, ignore that though and wrap the (optional) `<tbody>` around `<tr>` elements if they're not already present.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the  `<div class="tab_links">` and add this class to table then it will work 
Thanks

Comment: While this is definitely a correct approach, you really should take the time to explain *why* it's a correct approach, and what's wrong with the original HTML. We've left comments about it, but comments are temporary.

Comment: Well, as in ordered list and un ordered  list you can not use any thing without Li's , in tables tr td are the valid structure anything you want to use   in tables you need to wrap them in tr td , you can use anything in td for further details visit w3schools.

Comment: He doesn't want to add the class to the table as he is only trying to color the `<td>s` of two of the `<tr>s`, not the whole table.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is information you need to add to the question itself. And telling *anyone* (ever) to 'visit W3Schools' is not going to attract votes to your answers. Find a definite, specific link to find further information but summarise that information in your answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas , he is new i think in this field that is why i am suggesting him to visit in w3schools

Answer (score 0):

Add that class to the `<tr>` and remove the div:

```
<table>
    <!--profile-->
    <tr><td colspan="3">profile</td></tr>
    <!--tabs 2 rows-->
    <!--row 1-->
    <tr class="tab_links">
        <td class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--row 2-->
    <tr class="tab_links">
        <td><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab5">tab5</a></td>
        <td><a href="#tab6">tab6</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--detail of tab-->
    <tr><td colspan="3">detail of tab</td></tr>

</table>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/2L7d86p2/

Answer (score -2):

Edit background:#7fb5da; to background-color:#7fb5da;

Comment: old post I know - but background is 100% applicable